# Use functions and properties from one object in another object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Created an object **Blubb** which has to do some things. There are several of those objects. Now there is another object **BlubbWatcher** which when it has to it has to reset some things from **Blubb**.

I've tried to create `prototype.functions` and thought then I can use them later using `Object.create(Blubb)`. Now I can use the functions but the properties are empty/undefined cause I guess I don't have the right instance of **Blubb** in **BlubbWatcher**

Simplified example to demonstrate my problem:

```js
var Blubb = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.header = 'hello world';
    this.init();
};

Blubb.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log(this.header);
};

//////////////// 
var BlubbWatcher = function(sections){
    this.sections = sections;
    this.Blubb = Object.create(Blubb);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        this.sections,
        (function (element) {
            // call Blubb.init from here makes header undefined
            console.log(' - next log is undefined - ')
            this.Blubb.prototype.init(element);
        }).bind(this)
    );
};

//////////////////
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    sections,
    function (element, index) {
        new Blubb(element);
    }
);

new BlubbWatcher(sections);
```

```html
<section>section</section>
```

How can I use the functions and properties from **Blubb** in **BlubbWatcher**?

Comment: Do you just want `BlubbWatcher` to contain one or more `Blubb` objects? Or do you want some kind of inheritance-like relationship?

Comment: @FrankModica I would like to have an inheritance-like relationship

Comment: `Object.create` doesn't create properties unless you explicitly specify/pass them via second argument (see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for details). However if you already have a constructor (base class), you may `call` it in a subclass' constructor. Then you'll have properties autom'ly copied/inherited from a base class to a sub one. Or alternatively you may *instantiate* base class as a member of subclass using`new` operator: `this.Blubb = new Blubb();`

Comment: @hindmost do you mind setting up a demonstration fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Blubb = function(element, header) {
    this.element = element;
    this.header = header;
    this.init();
};

Blubb.prototype.init = function() {
    console.log(this.header, 'header');
};

////////////////
var BlubbWatcher = function(blubbs){
    this.blubbs = blubbs;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        this.blubbs,
        function (element) {
            console.log(' - next log is NOT undefined :) - ')
            element.init();
        }
    );
};

//////////////////
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var blubbs = Array.prototype.map.call(
    sections,
    function (element) {
        return new Blubb(
            element,
            document.querySelector('header')
        );
    }
);

new BlubbWatcher(blubbs);
```

I have rewritten your code. What happen is that you are actually creating new instances of Blubb in your BlubbWatcher instead of using the previous instances created.

In order to make it work, I have used `.map` on sections and got an array containing the instances of Blubb, then I've added these instances to the BlubbWatcher.

If you are in a browser and must support old browsers, consider using `lodash` library with `_.map`.

Comment: I've tried with your code https://jsfiddle.net/j7cpokar/ but browser console says: "Uncaught TypeError: sections.map is not a function"

Comment: I've updated my code and the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j7cpokar/2/, it is working for me :)